# Select elements using Selenium Webdriver PHP?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a number of page elements that I want to store in a variable and loop through using Selenium Webdriver PHP.

For example:

```
< cite > Name 1 < /cite >
< cite > Name 2 < /cite >
<cite > Name 3< /cite >
```

I am using the following code, but it doest give me the results from above(i.e. Name 1) etc. How do I grab the text from the  element using Selenium Webdriver.

```
$users = $driver->findElements(
  WebDriverBy::xpath('//cite')
)->getText();
foreach($users as $u)
         {
             echo $u;
         }
```

I am using Selenium Webdriver [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) wrapper

Comment: instead of `findElements()` you need to use `findElement()` to access `getText()`

Comment: yes but that only gets me the first element, it does not get all elements as an array / object that I can loop... how would I get all elements in the variable $users?

Comment: since I need to get all the text from multiple elements, any ideas? is there another method that grabs all elements ?

Comment: anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know PHP, but in Java, you'd do something similar to:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//cite"));
for (WebElement element: elements) {
  System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Given that, I'd assume that the PHP equivalent would be something like this:

```
$users = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('//cite'));
foreach($users as $u)
  {
    echo $u->getText();
  }
```

Comment: Tried it but gives me Fatal error: Call to a member function getText() on a non-object

Comment: Again, I'll be the first to admit that I know next to nothing about PHP, nor about the bindings you're using. The bottom line is that your initial code is flawed. `findElements()` should be returning you a list of objects, and iterating over the list of returned objects, you should be able to call `getText()` on each one. You'll need to figure out what the PHP bindings you're using are doing and what the structure is of the objects `findElements()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

JimEvan's answer is correct. If you're getting a "non-object" type error, you should check to make sure the findElements() call is actually returning something:

```
$users = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('//cite'));
fwrite(STDOUT, "Number of users: " . count($users));
```

Perhaps it has something to do with the space characters in your element tags (just a guess)?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code is.

```
$users = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('//cite')); foreach($users as $u) {echo $u->getText();}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more?